# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{-1/2} \ \ln^{2}(x) \ \ln^{2}(1-x) \ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals, zeta-functions

Can the integral 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac {\ln^{2}(x)~\ln^{2}(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}~\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
be evaluated in terms of $\zeta(3)$ and $\ln(2/\mathrm{e})$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "in terms of"? Any number can be written as a linear combination of $\zeta(3)$ and $\ln(2/\mathrm{e})$.

Comment: Mathematica calculated it as
$$56 \zeta (3) (\log (4)-4)-\pi ^4+16 (48+(\log (4)-12) \log (4))+\frac{8}{3} \pi ^2 (\log (64)-14)$$

Comment: The idea, in general, is to show the step by step process of the evaluation of the integral. This would either provide a method to show that Mathematica, or related, is correct or needs to have another result in its collection.

Comment: @FlybyNight your comment is indeed an interesting one and has spurred on the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793551/linear-combination-of-numbers-express-the-nth-fibonacci-number-in-terms-of

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible way to evaluate this integral is to start from
$$
B(s,t)=\int_0^1x^{s-1}(1-x)^{t-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(t+s)}
$$
Thus
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x\ln^2(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=\left.\frac{\partial^4}{\partial^2s\partial^2t}B(s,t)\right\vert_{(s,t)=(1,\frac{1}{2})}
$$
This yields after simplification
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x\ln^2(1-x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=
\frac{1}{3} \left(168 \zeta (3) (\ln 4-4)-3 \pi ^4+48
   (48+(\ln  4 -12) \ln  4 )+8 \pi ^2 (\ln
    64 -14)\right).
$$
In fact this simplification can be done using formulas about the Polygamma function,
like $(15)$ and $(16)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html). I thank [O.L.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73025/o-l) for this information.