# Linear combination of numbers: Express the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number in terms of known constants.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, zeta-functions

Given the concept that any number can be expressed as a combination of other numbers can the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number be expressed in terms of $\zeta(3)$ and $\ln(2/e)$ ? If possible, show all work in the derivation.
\begin{align}
F_{n} = \sum_{r} \left[ a_{r} \zeta^{r}(3) + b_{r} \ln^{r}(2/e) \right]
\end{align}
where $a_{r} \neq 0$ and $b_{r} \neq 0$ are to be determined.

Comment: Yes, take $f=0$ and $g=F_n/(\ln2-1)$.

Comment: You are indeed correct that if $F_{n} = f \zeta(3) + g \ln(2/e)$ then $f=0$ and $g = F_{n} \ln^{-1}(2/e)$. The original question was a case of "brain working, thoughts not".

Comment: Are you familiar with this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression